# Wicket form "ServletRequest does not contain multipart content"

Tags: forms, file-upload, wicket, multipartform-data, wicket-6

I have a wicket form that has a file upload box on it.  Sometimes this file upload box is hidden because the user isn't required to attach documentation.  **I have called** `setMultiPart(true)` **on the form object**, but I still (but only rarely) get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ServletRequest does not contain multipart content. One 
>   possible solution is to explicitly call Form.setMultipart(true), Wicket tries its best to 
>   auto-detect multipart forms but there are certain situation where it cannot.

Helpful facts:

- This form gets submitted about 10,000 times per day and I get this error 5-10 times per day.
- If the user that got the error fills out the form again with the same data it will work fine.
- I have never been able to replicate the error locally at all.
- The few users that I have talked to that have received this error say that they were not uploading a file.

Here is the condensed version of the form code:

```
Form<MyObject> form = new Form<MyObject>("form")
{       
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit()
        {
        //saving stuff here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onValidate()
        {
            super.onValidate();
            //This just highlights the fields on the form:
            visitChildren( FormComponent.class, new FormValidationVisitor() );
        }
}       

add(form);
form.setMultiPart(true);
form.setMaxSize(Bytes.kilobytes( 5120 ));
```

There is a custom Validator added to the form and there are some AJAX callbacks to some of the form fields, but the form itself isn't AJAXy.  Looking at the generated source in the browser I get the form declaration looking like this:

```
form id="form4a" action="../wicket/page?12-1.IFormSubmitListener-form" encType="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8"
```

The button that submits the form is a standard wicket **Button** on the Java side and an `input type="submit"` on the HTML side, although in the browser source view I do see a `jQuery18307179054977115189="23"` attribute on the input.

Any ideas?  I've tried every which way just to replicate this bug and cannot so ANY help you can give would be great. I am using Wicket 6.6.0.

Comment: A tip: You can format inline code with backquotes, like this: `

Comment: Thanks for cleaning that up for me!

Comment: How have you tried to reproduce it?

Comment: Yes, but nothing I do gives me the error.  I've tried filling out the form a million different ways, I've tried letting the session timeout before form submission, I've tried putting invalid data....etc, etc and so forth.

It is very frustrating to see the error come up in the logs and have no idea how to replicate it.

Comment: Did you tested by navigating using the browser back button to get to the form before submitting it ?

Comment: Just tried that and it had no effect.  Backward, then forward and back and forth again...nothing.   The users that have commented on the error (they have the opportunity to fill out an error form whenever they receive a runtime error) usually say they they just hit the submit button when they get the error screen.

Comment: I've also tried:  Uploading a zero byte file.  Uploading a file that doesn't exist.  Filling out the form, restarting the service, then submitting the form.  Filling out the form, waiting for the session to end, then submitting the form.

Comment: There may be a link between this error and server load.  I just noticed today that requests to the site were a little slow and then a couple of the errors popped up in the logs.  It may just be coincidence though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem just few minutes ago. Inside the outer form, I have a nested form for file upload component.
So, here is how I fixed:
My outer and inner forms both have setMultipart(true) and it works as expected.